# Eliminar tabulaciones de una cadena de texto en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy haciendo web scraping, recupero una cadena de texto (le asigno a una variable) pero tiene tabulaciones.

El código dentro del html:

```
<td class="superenalotto-extraction-archive__details__table__body__label">Concorso <strong>Nº 1</strong> del
                    <strong>3 Gennaio 2022</strong></td>
<td>
```

En Python le asigno una variable:

```
fecha = fila.find('td', class_='superenalotto-extraction-archive__details__table__body__label').text
```

Pero cuando lo imprimo por consola me muestra asi, revisando hay varias tabulaciones dentro del texto: (hey usado lstrip(), rstrip()... y nada)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo eliminar estas tabulaciones.

Gracias anticipadamente

Comment: `(texto.replace("\t", "")` Elimina los tabuladores (o puedes reemplazarlos con un espacio u otro caracter)

Comment: @CandidMoe Gracias si tambien probe con **replace** pero siempre hay un salto de linea (lo muestra en dos lineas).

Comment: Pues agrega otro replace que cambie "\n" por "" ...

Comment: Si estás haciendo *webscrapping*, lo suyo es usar un analizador de DOM. Como la librería interna [`xmlDOM`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html). Saludos